# Why do MapGet and similar methods not work if you access the HttpContext?

Tags: c#, .net, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

If you create a new .NET 7 Web Api project and try to map a route using `MapGet` or similar, it only actually maps the route if you don't use the HttpContext parameter. Why is this and how do I make it work?

Program.cs in a fresh project:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapGet("/endpoint1", () => "I work");
app.MapGet("/endpoint2", async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("i don't work"));

app.Run();
```

All I can figure out is that they appear to use different method overloads, and only one of them actually does its job.

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious, but there's nothing in any of the official documentation that I can see to explain what the difference is or how to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? This code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: I mean the route just doesn't get mapped. If you were to run this example, you'd get "/endpoint1" but no "/endpoint2".

Comment: No, this works fine [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J20PZ.png)

Comment: You're right, the routes just don't show up in Swagger and I wrongly assumed that meant that they didn't exist. Still a problem but a different one so I'll close the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't that the route doesn't get mapped, it actually gets mapped just fine so this is a non-issue. The reason that I thought the route didn't get mapped is because due to a bug/strange behaviour in .NET (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44970), Swagger doesn't pick up routes which use the HttpContext parameter on it's own.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).